# How to pass dollar prefixed keys to backend With angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application with a mongo as a DB.

I would like to reach a state where frontend can specify mongo queries and send them as objects to backend.

for example

```
{ 'name' : { '$exists' : 1 } }
```

The problem is that angular removes these keys from the query since it uses dollar signs for its own functionality.

However, this seems to be like a relevant use-case and I am sure there is a way to make this work.

Currently I am replacing the `$` sign with the word `dollar`and then in the backend I replace it back to `$`. silly but it works.

How can I improve this?

### EDIT

After using the `stringify` solution for a while, I discovered that indeed it is NOT GOOD TO KEEP DOLLAR PREFIXED PROPERTIES IN ANGULAR AT ALL!! 
Even though the solution worked fine for this specific problem, other issues started to arise.

For example:

- When I want to display the values on the scope momentarily, I simply output them on the page `{{data}}` - however that will remove dollar prefixed properties..
- When I use `$watch` or `angular.equal`, I will get wrong outcomes since these methods ignore dollar prefixed properties..

You could use do `angular.equal(JSON.stringify(obj1), JSON.stringify(obj2) )` or you could use `$scope.$watch(function(){ return JSON.stringify($scope.data); }, ... )` but that would be too much in my opinion. I revert back to my old method of using `dollar_` prefix. It is readable and plays well with the rest of angular. Writing conversion methods are easy.

You can also use `_$` instead of my `dollar_`. in mongo world please remember that turning `_$` to `$` should not be simply to remove the `_` character as mongo uses `_id` which will turn it to `id`..

Comment: how about replace $ with another symbol that angular doesn't use, like #,^,& or something else?

Comment: also, how about JSON.stringify the object, then send it back? and on the back end do JSON.parse

Comment: @EliteOctagon I will accept the JSON.stringify, especially because it seems that nodeJS already turns it to an object for me.. so no work in the backend. just a workaround for the angular dollar conundrum - want to write it as an answer?

Comment: At the risk of asking something you already know, are you sure you want to pass queries from the front side directly to the datastore backend? It sounds like you're opening the door to [injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection), risking both the stability of your web app and the privacy of your users.

Comment: @Barend - yes. This is an admin feature so I am fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just do

```
JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

and send that?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own request transformer. The default one is this one:

```
function(d) {
  return isObject(d) && !isFile(d) ? toJson(d) : d;
}
```

where `toJson` just calls `JSON.stringify` and thereby removes some properties. You can replace this `toJson(d)`call with a simple `JSON.stringify(d)`.

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses) explain how to override the defaults, either permanently or per request.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will read the documentations you sent as this seems valuable information anyway. 
I chose EliteOctagon's answer because it was first (by comment) and because it seems simpler.

Comment: @guymograbi No problem. I'm not here for the points :) But keep in mind that you need to call `JSON.stringify` for every request, compared to a one-time configuration. And don't forget that a simple `JSON.stringify` (in both solutions) would also send any angular specific properties as well as objects like window, document or the whole current scope, if an object had a reference to that.